# Automatically sort table data by specified column when opening attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, sorting, default

I want the attribute table in QGIS to be automatically sorted by the column I want, so that I don't have to click on the right column every time.

At the moment, when I open the attribute table, the sorting is done on the `"ID"` column, and the numbers are in random order, not in descending or ascending order.

Is this currently possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'points_test'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

As you can see there are two fields in it:

```
Name:id   | TypeName:Integer | Type:2  | Length:1
Name:TEST | TypeName:String  | Type:10 | Length:10
```

By default my values in the attribute table are sorted by `"id"` fields. How one can know that?

Open Attribute Table (<kbd>F6</kbd>) and proceed with `Right Mouse Click on the column header > Sort...`

[image: attribute_table]

Now, I will configure attribute table sort order and switch to another field. In the pop-up window insert the desired field, in my case it is `"TEST"`, instead of `"id"`.

[image: sort]

And now as you can see that my attribute table was visually changed into different sorting order evoked from the `"TEST"` field.

[image: result]

---

The same action can be performed with PyQGIS.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

config = layer.attributeTableConfig()

config.setSortExpression("TEST") # name of the field
config.setSortOrder(0) # 0:ascending 1:descending

layer.setAttributeTableConfig(config)

iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output the same as was achieved above.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Documentation | 14.4. Working with the Attribute Table » Sorting columns](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#sorting-columns)
- [QGIS Python API | QgsAttributeTableConfig](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Attribute/QgsAttributeTableConfig.html#module-QgsAttributeTableConfig)
- [GitHub | QGIS/tests/src/python/test_qgsattributetableconfig.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsattributetableconfig.py)
- [QGIS API Documentation | QgsAttributeTableConfig Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html)

Comment: Thanks, but why are integers sorted as strings? Seems only strings are sorted correctly.

Comment: @Taras It get saves, but does not work correctly for integer values.

Comment: @Taras Yes, it is `int4` type (the `ID` field). Also a field of type `date` is sorted incorrectly (like string values). The table is in the `PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension`.

Comment: @Taras Yes, it is a bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34935