# Permanently sorting table so that field of interest is sorted in the same order as the fid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, geopackage, sorting

Using 3.22.13, consider a non-spatial GeoPackage attribute table containing one text field, named `"field_a"`. This table has the following form:

*fid field_a*
1  B
2  A
3  X
4  C

How can I sort the table so that `"field_a"` is now permanently sorted in the same ascending order as the `"fid"`, as shown below?

*fid field_a*
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  X

If this sorting requires exporting to a new table, that is acceptable.

I have tried the **Order by expression** tool with **Expression** = `"field_a"`.  Unfortunately, it did not change the sort order in any way.

**Edit:**

After further review, I've been able to accomplish this task by:

1. Exporting the table as a *.csv* to Excel, without the `"fid"` field
2. Sorting the *.csv* within Excel by *field_a*, then saving
3. Add the re-sorted *.csv* to QGIS
4. Export the *.csv* as a GeoPackage table

Although this works, it is a little kludgy.  I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this sorting, preferably within QGIS. Also, I found no plugins that fit this need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with this query, than make it permanent/export/save it:

```sql
select *
from my_layer
order by field_a
```

---

**Be aware**: *if the initial layer contains a `"fid"` field, be sure to either create a new unique identifier field ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400741/88814)) to get the id in the same order as field_a. The other option: exclude the initial `"fid"` from the query. In this case, you can't select all (`select *`), but have to list all fields you want to export one by one (there is [no simple way to select all, but exclude one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)).*

If you have just two fields (`"fid"` and `"field_a"`, as in your example), you could use `select field_a, geometry from my_layer order by field_a`. Like this, the missing `"fid"` field will be automatically created when you save the layer as GeoPackage.

Comment: This was the simplest and easiest of the answers that were kindly offered.  However, there is one important qualification here: when exporting the virtual layer via *Export > Save features as...*, uncheck the *fid* field from the *Select fields to export and their export options* section of the *Save Vector Layer as...* window. This forces the target *fid* to be recalculated (I think!), so that *field_a* and *fid* are both sorted in the same ascending order (which was a requirement of my OP).  P.S., I am also eagerly awaiting the book :)

Comment: You're right, see updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use GeoPandas to sort the field `"field_a"` in ascending order and save it back to the GeoPackage with a new name.

Here is a sample code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

# update the path to select the geopackage file
gpkg = r'F:\Ahmad\Test\Test4\Geopackage\Test.gpkg'

# Update layer name with the table name
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpkg, layer='polygon_grid', driver="GPKG")  

# sort field_a in ascending order
gdf = gdf.sort_values(['FiledName']) # change FiledName to field_a in your case

# write the table back to the geopackage with a new name
gdf.to_file(gpkg, layer='polygon_grid_sorted', driver="GPKG")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One can try the [`setSortExpression()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#a1d7e63ce0bb3371e9be32d5a5f50d116) and [`setSortOrder()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#a7cb7125ec881d69108242e15cd38cbe0) methods of the `QgsAttributeTableConfig` class.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def sorting_table_by_column(layer_name: str, column_name: str, sort_order: int) -> None:
    """
    Sets permanent sorting by a column in the attribute table
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param column_name: name of the target column
    :param sort_order: ascending(0) or descending(1) sorting order
    """

    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    layer_attr_table_config.setSortExpression(column_name)
    layer_attr_table_config.setSortOrder(sort_order)

    layer.setAttributeTableConfig(layer_attr_table_config)
    
    return
    
sorting_table_by_column('points', "String", 0)
```

*Initial input:*
[image: input]

Change the parameters of the function in the last line. Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [Automatically sort table data by specified column when opening attribute table in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422180/automatically-sort-table-data-by-specified-column-when-opening-attribute-table-i)