# How to create a QGIS Virtual Layer that retains the source field types?

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

In [a previous question that I posted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447872/), the answer that I accepted involved creating a Virtual Layer from a source layer.  The query used to create the Virtual Layer was:

```
select *  
from my_layer  
order by field_a
```

Although the query works as intended, some of the source field types are converted to different types in the Virtual Layer.  Specifically:

- Integer (32 bit) are converted to Integer (64 bit)
- Date and Date&Time are converted to Text (string)
- Boolean are converted to Integer (64 bit)

I use the Refactor Fields to get the field types back to their original, but this involves another step that I would prefer to eliminate.

Question: How to create a Virtual Layer that retains the source field types?

Comment: Have you tried a cast (e.g. mydate::DATE) for those fields?

Comment: See what Virtual layer context help says: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAz7E.png "where type can be any of *int*, *real* or *text*". So this seems to suggest that virtual layers do not support fieldtypes like *Date&Time* or *Boolean*, but I might be wrong. See also here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#special-comments

Comment: I think the problem lies with SQLITE, which knows only limited data types: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: You could experiment with the OGR Virtual Format, where you have more options to define your field types: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html. After loading your XML description (i.e. myfile.vrt) into QGIS you could replace the layer datasource with the content of your VRT file using the changeDataSource plugin.

Comment: The answer clearly involves the lack of field type support for Date, Time, and Boolean.  @Babel was the first to point this out, so if you'd like to form your comment as an answer I'd be happy to credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual layers lack field type support for Date, Time, and Boolean. See what Virtual layer context help says:

> where type can be any of int, real or text

[image]

See also here: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#special-comments

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a possibility to define the resulting field-type of a virtual layer, but as workaround You could create the virtual layer with a query that contains only the absolute necessary fields and add all other fields via join from the original layers.

That has multiple advantages:

1. simple queries for the virtual layer
2. attribute-tables and dialogs, which show clear, from where the fields come
3. correct (and all) field-types from original layers

So create virtual_lyr with something like

```
select 
id_field
from my_layer  
order by field_a
```

And then join all other data with layer-properties-dialogue or via Python:

```
join_info = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
join_info.setJoinLayer(my_layer)
join_info.setJoinFieldName(id_field)
join_info.setTargetFieldName(id_field)
join_info.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
virtual_lyr.addJoin(join_info)
```

One possible disadvantage:

The resulting layers with simple query and join could be less performant than the with complex queries without join, I haven't tested this so far.

hth
Ludwig

Comment: Using a join is an interesting approach, but it's probably just as complicated as Refactoring.

Comment: Refactoring QGis-Source-Code is appreciated, but far beyond my knowledge, I'm afraid...