# Change search order for 1-to-1 join attributes by field value

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have 2 layers, a point one named "networks" and non-spatial one named "transactions". The transaction layer has a field named "network_id" referencing the network for which the transaction was made as well as the date the transaction was made.

What I'd like to do is to retrieve the date of the last transaction for each network and fill a new field in the network layer with this information. For that I tried using the "join attributes by field value" algorithm on both fields, keeping only the "transaction_date" field to be added to the network layer. I set the join type to "1-to-1" in order to get one value only. However, since a given network may have several transactions to it, the date I retrieve is not always corresponding to the last transaction made.

Is it possible to change the order the "join" algorithm search through records ?

Eg. could I change the way my transaction table is stored internally so that when the algorithm performs the join, it will stumble upon the last transaction first, since the table will already be sorted as I want. I tried what [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447872/permanently-sorting-table-so-that-field-of-interest-is-sorted-in-the-same-order) suggests but it doesn't work, perhaps because I'm working with dates instead of strings/integers.