# What is QDomNode and QDomDocument in terms of PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, xml, pyqt

On a low level what is `QDomNode` and `QDomDocument` in the PyQGIS context?

I comprehend that both [`QDomNode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomnode.html) and [`QDomDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomdocument.html) are derived from PyQt. Hence, with my limited knowledge of PyQt, I simply do not know how to operate with these classes.

For instance, if I want to save attribute table settings with the [`writeXml()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#add8bcda1a6d24f3e0beb02cdec4062f1) method from the `QgsAttributeTableConfig` class. But then I am petrified because I do know the gist of the required `QDomNode`.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()

attr_table_config.writeXml(...)
# What should be done here ?
```

Searching on GIS SE does not really provide any clarifications.

`help(QgsVectorLayer().attributeTableConfig().writeXml)` does not help at all.

> ```
> Help on built-in function writeXml:
>
> writeXml(...) method of qgis._core.QgsAttributeTableConfig instance
>     writeXml(self, node: QDomNode)
>     Serialize to XML on layer save
> ```

Comment: It looks like it wants an XML node, which must be part of a document. See this [test](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/406e1d6b9a38fdbbe320de192177753dbef0d7e4/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorlayer_namedstyle.py#L27C7-L27C7) for an example using a similar function

Comment: @JGH, thank you so much for such a useful URL!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what `QDomNode` and `QDomDocument` are in the Qt context:

> The [`QDomDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomdocument.html#details)class represents the entire XML document. Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides the primary access to the document's data.

> The [`QDomNode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomnode.html) class is the base class for all the nodes in a DOM tree.

> DOM provides an interface to access and change the content and structure of an XML file. It makes a hierarchical view of the document (a tree view). ......
>
> All DOM nodes in the document tree are subclasses of `QDomNode`. The document itself is represented as a `QDomDocument` object.

In the PyQGIS context, `QDomDocument` refers to XML structure used in XML-like files such as `.qgs`, `.qml`, `.sld` etc.

`writeXml` converts(serializes) the configuration data contained in `attr_table_config`  object to XML text. But it requires a `QDomNode` object to write the data to that object. A `QDomDocument` object is also a `QDomNode` object. Therefore, you can pass a `QDomDocument` object to the function.

```
doc = QDomDocument("myAttributeTableConfig") 
attr_table_config .writeXml(doc)
```

What about later? Now you can save the configuration as XML.

```
f = QFile("c:/test/test.xml")
result = f.open(QFile.WriteOnly)
if result:
    stream = QTextStream(f)
    doc.save(stream, 2) #2: amount of space to indent a node.
    f.close()
```

Here is an exmple for a simple attribute table as shown in the image below
:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE myAttributeTableConfig>
<attributetableconfig actionWidgetStyle="dropDown" sortOrder="0" sortExpression="">
  <columns>
    <column type="field" hidden="0" name="id" width="142"/>
    <column type="field" hidden="0" name="isim" width="300"/>
    <column type="actions" hidden="1" width="-1"/>
  </columns>
</attributetableconfig>
```

[image]

Or you can add the configuration to an existing XML atructure.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# make xml document
doc = QDomDocument("FooBar") 

# add an element to xml
foobar = doc.createElement("foobarconfig")
# foobar is QDomElement. QDomElement is also QDomNode.

config = layer.attributeTableConfig()

# write the configuration to foobar element(node)
config.writeXml(foobar) 

# add foobar element to doc
doc.appendChild(foobar)

f = QFile("c:/test/test.xml")
result = f.open(QFile.WriteOnly)
if result:
    stream = QTextStream(f)
    doc.save(stream, 2)
    f.close()
```

Result:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE FooBar>
 <foobarconfig> <!--HERE -->
  <attributetableconfig actionWidgetStyle="dropDown" sortOrder="0" sortExpression="">
    <columns>
      <column type="field" hidden="0" name="id" width="142"/>
      <column type="field" hidden="0" name="isim" width="300"/>
      <column type="actions" hidden="1" width="-1"/>
    </columns>
  </attributetableconfig>
</foobarconfig>
```

Answer (score 5):

After certain trials and errors, I was able to perform exporting/importing configurations of the layer's attribute table, see [Saving and applying layout of columns in QGIS Attribute Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470821/saving-and-applying-layout-of-columns-in-qgis-attribute-table).

Despite a great answer from @KadirŞahbaz, I would like to add some basic details regarding the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) in the scope of PyQGIS.

---

**The DOM : Document Object Model** - defines a standard for accessing and manipulating documents (changing document's structure, style, or content) with a logical tree, e.g. HTML, SVG, or XML. Each branch of the tree ends in a node, and each node contains objects.

**The XML DOM** - is a standard for getting, changing, adding, and deleting XML elements. It presents an XML document as a tree structure.

**The XML : eXtensible Markup Language** - is a markup language and file format, designed to store and transport data, to be self-descriptive and both human- and machine-readable, and is a W3C Recommendation.

All XML elements can be accessed through the XML DOM.

The XML DOM is:

- a standard object model for XML
- a standard programming interface for XML
- platform- and language-independent
- a W3C standard

According to the XML DOM, everything in an XML document is a node:

- The entire document is a document node
- Every XML element is an element node
- The text in the XML elements are text nodes
- Every attribute is an attribute node
- Comments are comment nodes

---

Now let's switch to QGIS. Obviously, it comes with some embedded XML Python Packages e.g. [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html), [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/), [`xmlrpc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html), and others (possible to see with `help("modules xml")`). However, QGIS uses the [`QtXml`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtxml-module.html) module to provide a C++ implementation of the DOM standard for XML.

The `PyQt5.QtXml` module contains two previously mentioned classes:

| class | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| [`QDomDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomdocument.html) | Represents an XML document (a text file with a tree structure) |
| [`QDomNode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomnode.html) | The base class for all the nodes in a DOM tree (a DOM model constructed as a tree of Objects) |

So, how to use the `writeXml()` method?

First of all, it requires a node i.e. `QDomNode`. Simply saying a spot, where to to insert the structured content of the `QgsAttributeTableConfig`.

Secondly if one decides to export that node into something like XML looking, one needs a certain approach. So, the `QDomDocument` class can be used. It has some methods. Another approach was shown by @KadirŞahbaz with the `QTextStream` class for reading and writing text.

---

**References:**

- [The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) | XML](https://www.w3.org/XML/)
- [W3Schools | XML Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)
- [mdn | Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- [Is the XML declaration node mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679136/is-the-xml-declaration-node-mandatory)
- [Converting QDomElement to QString / Container class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244459/converting-qdomelement-to-qstring-container-class)